# Zapier CLI how to use trigger_fields

Tags: zapier-cli

How do I replace the `path param` template in the url of a trigger ?

This is my current code, but I get an error saying that the

> "The client {{client_id}} doesn't exist."

I take it that the `{{client_id}}` template is not being replaced, here's my code:

```
const listEvents = (z, bundle) => {

    console.log('listing events.. ');

    const requestOpts = {
        url: 'https://wccqa.on24.com/wcc/api/v2/client/{{client_id}}/event',
        params: {
            client_id: bundle.inputData.client_id
        }
    };

    var eventResults =  z.request(requestOpts)
                         .then((response) => z.JSON.parse(response.content));

    z.console.log(eventResults);

    return eventResults;
};

module.exports = {
  //config ... 
}
```

Does the `params: {client_id: bundle.inputData.client_id}` not replace this template ?

Also, sometimes I get the following error when running `zapier test`:

> 1) GetEvents trigger testing should load latest Event created:
>        Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

You're correct, as written the curlies aren't being replaced. They're only replaced when you use the [shorthand notation](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#shorthand-http-requests), which might work for you here.

Otherwise, you can use [regular requests](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#manual-http-requests).

The easiest thing is to build your url with [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const url = `https://wccqa.on24.com/wcc/api/v2/client/${bundle.inputData.client_id}/event`
```

Everything else looks like it'll work as you intend.